# Getting undefined method in Controller yet method exists and works in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to build a simple web app that takes data passed in to a text field and delivers it to an API. I have created a model with some methods to do some basic calls to the API. I have set up a form with a text field and a submit button to pass along the data to a controller. When I submit I am getting an error that the method I am calling is not defined. Yet if I go in the console and try the same thing it works as expected. Any suggestions on what I am missing?

Model:

```
    def update(serial, deploy_value)

        HTTParty.post("#{BASE_URL}devices/update/serial/#{serial}?#{API_KEY}", 

            :body => {"customFieldValues": [{"name": "Deploy","value": "#{deploy_value}"}] }.to_json,
            :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
        )

    end
```

Controller

```
class GroundControlController < ApplicationController
require 'GroundControl'

def update
    serial = params[:serial]
    GroundControl.new.update(serial, "TEST")
    redirect_to(:back)
end

end
```

The error I am getting:

NoMethodError in GroundControlController#update
undefined method `update' for GroundControl:0x007fa062aa1298

From the console I can do the following:

```
2.3.0 :002 > require 'GroundControl'
 => true 
2.3.0 :003 > test = GroundControl.new
 => #<GroundControl:0x007fa2676a8838> 
2.3.0 :004 > GroundControl.new.update("ABC123", "TEST")
 => #<HTTParty::Response:0x7fa2671fb218 parsed_response={"id"=>43270, "serial"=>"ABC123", "udid"=>nil, "name"=>nil, "model"=>nil, "os"=>nil, "connected"=>false, "customFieldValues"=>[{"name"=>"Deploy", "value"=>"TEST"}]}, @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @headers={"server"=>["nginx/1.6.3"], "date"=>["Tue, 12 Apr 2016 15:09:27 GMT"], "content-type"=>["application/json; charset=utf-8"], "content-length"=>["150"], "connection"=>["close"], "access-control-allow-origin"=>["*"]}> 
2.3.0 :005 >
```

More info on the error I am getting:

NoMethodError in GroundControlController#update
undefined method `update' for #

```
Extracted source (around line #10):
8    def update
9    serial = params[:serial]
10   GroundControl.new.update(serial, "TEST")
11   redirect_to(:back)
12
13   end
```

Comment: does it tell you the line number for the error ?, I think you need to include a little bit more of the error stack. Looks like the error is from GroundControl.new.update. Because the Controller's action is being executed.

Comment: Could you post exactly what you are trying at the console? Is `update` an instance method of `GroundControl`?

Comment: If `GroundControl` is really a Rails model in `app/models`, then remove the `require 'GroundControl'` line form your controller. It is not needed. Models are auto-loaded in Rails.

Comment: I updated my original question with more info. I also removed require GroundControl in my controller.